# Error when trying to load login/registration pages

Tags: asp.net, razor

When I try to load any pages for registration or login, I get this error:

Stack Trace:

```
    [MissingMemberException: Public member 'IsEmpty' on type 'String' not found.]
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Container.GetMembers(String& MemberName, Boolean ReportErrors) +248
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.ObjectLateGet(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack) +61
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGet(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack) +163
    ASP._Page_Account_Register_vbhtml.Execute() +1940
    System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +199
    System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy(IEnumerable`1 executors) +69
    System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +131
    System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +78
    System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext context) +226
```

I've used IsEmpty several times throughout my code.  I'm not certain as to what the issue is, as the code runs fine on my system, but when I upload it and try to run the site, it throws this error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like IsEmpty is an extension method, you'll have to add reference to where is defined.

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web" />
            .....
            <add namespace="YourWeb.Where.ExtensionsAre" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web>
```

That goes on the view's Web.config